# how to determine if current user is admin in wordpress gutenberg UI

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, roles, wordpress-gutenberg

I have found `.canUser()` method. But it returns `undefined` for me.
I'm calling it in UI with:

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).canUser('create', 'users')
```

Where am I wrong?
Here are the docs for reference:
[enter link description here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core/#canUser)

Is there any known plausible way to do it in JS UI plugin code itself? Or how did you do it maybe?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `useSelect` in order to achieve this:

```
wp.data.useSelect( (select) => select( 'core' ).canUser( 'create', 'users' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

After Analyzing Gutenberg source for a bit found out I was semi right.
The way to check this is around users (only admin can do that).
Here is how one could do it in Gutenberg UI Block code.

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).canUser( 'create', 'users' )
```

THe only problem it did not work while the breakpoint was set.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `current_user_can()` to check the user roles.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

```
function current_user_can( $capability ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $current_user ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );
    $args = array_merge( array( $capability ), $args );

    return call_user_func_array( array( $current_user, 'has_cap' ), $args );
}
```

To check if the user is editor or administrator:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?>
    // Stuff here for administrators or editors
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes. I have seen this way. Thank you anyways! My thought if there is a way to do it in Plugin UI code itself (e.g. JavaScript part)